# Running into c++ visual studio compiler error "htonf" while compiling the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am running into a couple of errors related to "htonf" c++ function error while compiling my code. Help will be much appreciated.

Following are the errors:

**Error C2556   'long htonf(float)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'unsigned int htonf(float)'**

**Error C2371   'htonf': redefinition; different basic types    ecueHost**

**Error C2065   'htonf': undeclared identifier**

The error is appearing in the datapacket.cpp below

```
#include "str.h"
#include "DataPacket.h"
#include "exception.h"
#include "message.h"
#include "object.h"
#include "util.h"


#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH  4096

long htonf(float f)
{
    long x;
    x = *((long*)&f);
    x = htonl(x);
    return x;
}

float ntohf(long l)
{
    float f;
    l = ntohl(l);
    f = *((float*)&l);
    return f;
}
```

In the "winsock2.h" header file included in "datapacket.h" header, the "htonf" is defined as under:

```
#ifndef htonf
__inline unsigned __int32 htonf ( float Value ) 
{ 
unsigned __int32 Tempval;
unsigned __int32 Retval;
Tempval = *(unsigned __int32*)(&Value);
Retval = _WS2_32_WINSOCK_SWAP_LONG 
(Tempval);
return Retval;
}
#endif /* htonf */
```

and in the "datapacket.cpp" file itself the "htonf" is also declared here

```
// Store a float to the datapacket
TDataPacket& TDataPacket::operator<<(float f)
{
long x = htonf(f);
return SerializingIn(&x, LONG_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: The clue is in the second error message `'htonf': redefinition;`. What that means is that one (or more) of those header files you've included is declaring `htonf` in a different way to what you are using in `datapacket.cpp`. So have a look through the header files for `htonf` and post anything you find here.

Comment: Could you please attempt to create a [mcve] to show us? When and where and *how* are you *declaring* those functions?

Comment: Incidentally that code is very dubious because it assumes that a `float` and a `long` are the same size, which isn't necessarilly true (especially in the age of 64 bit computing). Where did you get it from?

Comment: By the way, doing type-punning like that breaks [*strict aliasing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). You need to go through byte (`char`) arrays to be fully compliant.

Comment: @john this is a pretty old code which I am trying to recompile

Comment: @john I have posted the declaration of htonf in header file. Can you suggest something now please?

Comment: Just take advantage of the #ifndef in the winsock2 header file.  `#define htonf htonf`gets the job done.  You don't even have to change the code, set the compile option to define the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error C2556 'long htonf(float)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'unsigned int htonf(float)'
```

This error message explains it completely.

You have:

```
__inline unsigned __int32 htonf ( float Value )
```

in winsock2.h, and

```
long htonf(float f)
```

in datapacket.cpp.  Your easiest solution will be to change the definition of `htonf()` in datapacket.cpp to match what you have in winsock2.h, and adjust the implementation as needed to reflect the new return type.

First of all, `long` is signed while `unsigned __int32` is unsigned, and secondly, even though they are the same size under MSVC, `__int32` and `long` are not interchangeable data types.